# Get the maximum value of a list with three numbers

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, lispworks

I'm learning Lisp now, and I'm trying to do an exercise that asks me to get the maximum value of a list, the syntax is totally different from most programming languages I've learned, so I'm having some difficulties.

My code:

```
 (defun test(y)
     (cond
          ((and (first y) (> (second y)) (> (third y))) 
        (format t "numero maximo ~d" (first y))
          ((and (second y) (> (first y)) (> (third y))) 
        (t (format t "numero maximo ~d" (second y))
          ((and (third y) (> (second y)) (> (first y))) 
        (t (format t "numero maximo ~d" (third y))
    ))
```

I'm receiving this error: `incomplete s-expression in region`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is too complex, it tries to take elements from a list, compare them, and print something. Like in other languages, use smaller functions and, particularly with a new language, test often in order to avoid having to debug something too large.

Your code, automatically indented with Emacs, looks as follows:

```
(defun test(y)
  (cond
    ((and (first y) (> (second y)) (> (third y)))
     (format t "numero maximo ~d" (first y))
     ((and (second y) (> (first y)) (> (third y)))
      (t (format t "numero maximo ~d" (second y))
         ((and (third y) (> (second y)) (> (first y)))
          (t (format t "numero maximo ~d" (third y))
             ))
```

And the editor complains about unbalanced parentheses:

- In `(> (second y))`, the `>` function is given only one argument
- All your `cond` clauses are in fact nested inside the first clause. Using an editor that highlights matching parentheses helps a lot here. The syntax should be:

  ```
  (cond
    (test-1 ...)
    (test-2 ...)
    (t ...))
  ```

  If your test involves calling predicates, then it looks like:

  ```
  (cond
    ((and (f1 ...) (f2 ...)) ;; <-- test
     ... ;; <-- code
    ) ;; end of first clause
  ) ;; end of cond
  ```

  But note that you do not need to put comments for closing delimiters, the indentation and the automatic highlighting of parentheses should help you avoid mistakes.

Let's try a rewrite.

First of all, you can write a function that just compares numbers, not thinking about lists or formatting; here is a very straightforward `max-of-3` implementation (without cheating and calling the built-in `max` function):

```
(defun max-of-3 (x y z)
  (if (> x y)
      (if (> x z) x z)
      (if (> y z) y z)))
```

Evaluate the function, and test it on multiple inputs, for example in the REPL:

```
CL-USER> (max-of-3 0 2 1)
2
....
```

Then, you can build up the other function, for your list:

```
(defun test (list)
   (format t 
           "numero maximo ~d"
           (max-of-3 (first list)
                     (second list)
                     (third list))))
```

If you need to do more error checking ahead of time, like checking that the lists is well-formed, you should probably define other auxiliary functions.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question and answer, I might be able to provide a solution or two that returns the max, regardless of the length of the list. So, these solutions are not limited to a list of three.

This illustrates a way to test where "max-lst" is the Lisp function under test:

```
(defconstant test-case 
  (list 1 2 0 8 7 6 9 4 5))

(defun run-test ()
  (max-lst test-case))
```

### Solution 1

This solution uses recursion. If you like loops better, Lisp has several loops. The Lisp function "max" is not used:

```
(defun max-lst (lst-in)
  (cond ((null (second lst-in))
         (first lst-in))

        ((> (first lst-in) (second lst-in))
         (max-lst
          (list* (first lst-in) (rest (rest lst-in)))))

        (t
         (max-lst
          (list* (rest lst-in))))))
```

### Solution 2

If you have no objection to using the Lisp function "max," here is a solution using max.

Note that max is not limited to two arguments.

```
(max 5 6 4 7 3)
```

will return 7.

In this solution, the function "max" is passed to the function "reduce" as an argument. The "reduce" function takes a function and a list as arguments. The function is applied to each adjacent pair of arguments and returns the result. If you want the sum, you can pass the + argument.

```
(defun max-lst-using-max (lst-in)
  (reduce #'max lst-in))
```

---

Alas, I fear that I provide these solutions too late to be pertinent to the original poster. But maybe someone else will have a similar question. So, perhaps this could help, after all.